# I cannot get to install Ubuntu

Tags: installation, dual-boot, wubi

Every time I try to install Ubuntu I get errors. I get the same error:

```
Invalid argument
```

The versions which I've tried so far are:

- 11.04
- 12.04
- 13.04

I don't have CD's so I have mounted the images with Daemon Tools Ultra and I get the same errors.

I get the error after I've inputted the password and username, options for HDD, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're booting to Windows, mounting an `.iso` then using that `.iso` to install Ubuntu on top of the Windows you're currently running? That's never gonna work.

What you need to do is install the `.iso` to a USB drive in a way that makes it bootable. Google `unetbootin`, find it, download it, and use it to create that bootable USB.

Then change your BIOS settings to boot from that USB. Then you're going to make some choices. First, do you want to wipe Windows and make this an Ubuntu only machine, or do you want to dual-boot so you can use either? Answer that question before you install Ubuntu.

**And for god's sake, back up everything you don't want to lose first!**

Comment: i want to wipe windows.

Comment: ty for help.anyway i wanna wipe all the content which i have now on the computer.

Comment: Still, copy any files, pictures, music, etc., that you don't want to lose somewhere else for safe keeping. Being new, go with a simple installation. If this is an old, slow system, you might want to consider `Lubuntu`. It's less demanding. When you've created your bootable USB, you'll boot off it. Connect the internet if you can, and click on the `Install~ icon, and you should be off. (Skip disk encryption, go with the defaults.) You should be prepared to reinstall once you've tried everything out and you see how things go and what you might want to do differently.

Comment: thank you...still tough i m going to try it later because i havent slept for 2 days...that could be one of the reasons why i think so slow and my english skillz are down.

Comment: we will talk after i install it.and if you can tell me more about this/things which i really need to know please dont hesitate to tell me because i m new to this:D.nn

Comment: so thank you for the support.i have it installed and it runs smoothly.you are my hero:D